# Matrix from 3 columns with values (not sum)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm want to show values in a matrix instead of columns, but can not figure out if this is possible in Excel...

Have 3 columns with values and want a matrix where there might several values in one matrix-cell... Se example...

Hope for any help...

[image: Example]

Comment: This video on YouTube might help. I was going to show  you step by step with your data, but I can't add a new measure to a pivot table right now. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiFzVInI5sg

Comment: Excellent. I will try it out...

Comment: Worked well. Thank You so much @BradR